# Is there any rule on the convergence of an infinite alternate series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, rational-numbers

Can we say if an infinite alternate series sums to a rational number given some specific conditions? Assuming the series converges, is there any test to know if it sums to a rational value? I know there is a similar question mentioned in the comment that basically seems to suggest that this is still an open question in mathematics. However, the kind of infinite series I am talking about in here is alternate ones. In other words, if we add "alternating" characteristics to an infinite series, does the problem still remains open?

Comment: Well, not really.  Specific cases may have more information attached to them.

Comment: For some series, like the series definition of $e$, you can prove by contradiction that $e$ is irrational. But I agree with lulu: in general it is difficult and in many simple cases, it is not known whether the sum of a convergent series is rational or irrational.

Comment: For example, it took many years to prove that $\sum n^{-3}$ is irrational, and no one knows whether $\sum n^{-5}$ is. I realize these are not alternating, but I don't think that makes any difference. Take any real number whatsoever, and you can write it as an alternating series. $\pi=4-1+.2-.1+.05-.01+.002-.001+\cdots$

Comment: As already suggested, any convergent series can be rewritten as a convergent alternating series, so I can't imagine the question becomes easier just by sticking in the word, "alternating". $2-1+(2/2^5)-(1/2^5)+(2/3^5)-(1/3^5)+\cdots$ is no easier to analyze than $\sum n^{-5}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson For $k > 1$, $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^{n + 1} n^{-k} = \left(1 - 2^{1 - k}\right) \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-k}$, so for integer $k$ each series converges to a rational value iff the other does.

Comment: @Travis, right, and for odd $k\ge5$, no one knows whether either series has a rational value.

Comment: Right, I just meant to indicate that for series $\sum n^{-k}$ it's not too hard to translate the question of rationality to the same question about a related alternating series, placing it in the scope of o.p.'s question. It is known, curiously, that at least one of $\zeta(5), \zeta(7), \zeta(9), \zeta(11)$ must be irrational. https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=427&option_lang=eng